# Passing both member functions and lambdas to std::function

Tags: c++, function, events, std-function

I'm trying to create control/window events similar to how they are done in C#'s Windows Forms/WPF. Each event class contains an argument type and passes that as well as a pointer to the sending object. This is all fine and dandy when using a lambda function, but when I try to add a member function to the event I get a compile error of `C2276 '&': illegal operation on bound member function expression` and `C2660  'Event<MouseButtonEventArgs>::add': function does not take 1 arguments`.

How would I create an event class that can take lambda functions and member functions from any class (whether or not that class is the "sender")?

Event.h

```
template<class Args> struct EventListener {

    /* The function type to be called by the event. */
    typedef function<void(ControlBaseSPtr, Args&)> ArgsFunction;
    string name;
    ArgsFunction function;
};

template<class Args> class Event {

    /* The function type to be called by the event. */
    typedef function<void(ControlBaseSPtr, Args&)> ArgsFunction;
    deque<EventListener<Args>> listeners;

    Event(EventDirections direction) {
        this->direction = direction;
    }

    void add(const string& name, ArgsFunction function) {
        EventListener<Args> listener = EventListener<Args>(name, function);
        for (auto it = listeners.begin(); it != listeners.end(); it++) {
            if (it->name == name) {
                throw exception("Event::operator+= listener already exists in the event");
            }
        }
        listeners.push_back(listener);
    }

    //...
};
```

Control.h

```
class ControlBase {
    Event<MouseEventArgs> _eventMouseMovedGlobal;
    Event<MouseButtonEventArgs> _eventMouseButtonGlobal;

    ControlBase();

    void onMouseMovedGlobal(ControlBaseSPtr sender, MouseEventArgs e);
};
```

Control.cpp

```
ControlBase::ControlBase() {
    // Works
    _eventMouseButtonGlobal.add("some name", [](ControlSPtr control, MouseButtonEventArgs e){
        //...
    };

    // Doesn't work
    _eventMouseMovedGlobal.add("some name", bind(&onMouseMovedGlobal, this, placeholders::_2))
    // Doesn't work
    _eventMouseMovedGlobal.add("some name", bind(&onMouseMovedGlobal, this))
}

void ControlBase::onMouseWheelGlobal(ControlBaseSPtr sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since `onMouseMovedGlobal` has 2 input arguments, you need placeholders or values for both of them when creating a binder. So, instead of

`_eventMouseMovedGlobal.add("some name", bind(&onMouseMovedGlobal, this, placeholders::_2))`

you need

`_eventMouseMovedGlobal.add("some name", bind(&ControlBase::onMouseMovedGlobal, this, placeholders::_1, placeholders::_2))`

Comment: This only produces an additional error of `C2672 'bind': no matching overloaded function found` at compile time.

Comment: Probably you just need to replace `&onMouseMovedGlobal` with `&ControlBase::onMouseMovedGlobal`. Actually the former should not compile indeed.

Comment: Yup that was it. I just figured that out on my own to. Thank you.